# Is there a penalty box for this site?

Tags: discussion

I know that multiple SEs have a 'penalty box' is that also true for this SE? If so, do you lose all of your rep when you are put in it?

Comment: All SE sites now have penalty boxes. English SE is no different in this respect.

Comment: You're not planning to find yourself in it, I hope!

Comment: No, I just haven't seen any reference to it on this site, and I wasn't sure whether it was only on the Photography SE, or it was on all SE's.

Answer (score 7):

You can find more information in ["A Day in the Penalty Box"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) from the Stackoverflow Blog.

The relevant part in terms of what actually happens:

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days. That means:
>
> - Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
> - Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
> - You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.
>
> At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal. We don’t hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back.

There is a penalty box for all StackExchange sites.  EL&U is no exception.

Comment: "from 1 to 365 days", I have heard that exisit one hig-rep user suspended for three years (~1000 days). Is this suspension period in contrast with the rules? Or is that an exception? Or what? (+1 for the completeness of your answer)

Comment: @Carlo There is at least one such user. He was suspended for egregious rule violations after the mods tried for months to help him learn to use the site correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, English Language & Usage has a penalty box. When a user is placed in it, his reputation displays as 1 during the time of his "sentence", and is then recalculated when it's over. The rep doesn't go anywhere--it's just locked.